# Baseball simulation/risk analysis using Model Risk

Tags: excel, add-in, simulation, risk-analysis

I'm trying to run a baseball simulation using the ModelRisk Excel add-in. I have a list of probabilities for every outcome of a batter being at bat (i.e. probability X for a home run, probability Y for a single, Z for a double, etc.), and I'd like to simulate games with this data.

Each inning would be realistic so, after each event I would want to count whether the result is and out or not. For instance:

```
Batter 1: Result = Home Run. Out = 0.
Batter 2: Result = Strike. Out = 0. 
Batter 2: Result = Strike. Out = 0.
Batter 2: Result = Strike. Out = 1.
```

Etc.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I suppose I just need an example that I can build off of since I've never done this particular analysis before.

Comment: why the mathematica tag?

Comment: I think this can be done with a variety of tools, including Mathematica, and there isn't a ModelRisk tag.